# Разблокировать поле и запросить его заполнения

Tags: jquery

Есть условие type==2 && cause == 21 && date_response.val() и требующее выбор поля satisf.
Но satisf заблокировано другим скриптом.

Но его можно разблокировать, дописав строчку `$('#satisf').attr("disabled",false);`

Можно ли выполнить условие, одновременно разблокировавшее satisf и требовать его заполнения?

В моем примере ниже, поле satisf разблокируется и при выборе все равно требует выбора поля

```
 if ($('#type').val()==2 && $('#cause').val() == 21 && $('#date_response').val()) {
     $('#satisf').attr("disabled",false);
         $('.errorrep').append('<h3>Выберите поле Удовлетворена</h3>');
            $('.errorrep').css({'display':'block'});
            $('#draggable').animate({
                scrollTop:  0
            });
            return false;
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($('#type').val()==2 && $('#cause').val() == 21 && $('#date_response').val() && $('#satisf').val() == 0) {
     $('#satisf').attr("disabled",false);
         $('.errorrep').append('<h3>Выберите поле Удовлетворена</h3>');
            $('.errorrep').css({'display':'block'});
            $('#draggable').animate({
                scrollTop:  0
            });
            return false;
          }
```